# Глобальные горячие клавиши

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, hotkeys, keyboardhook

Пишу для себя програмку для упрощения работы.
Суть програмы - запуститься, свернуться в трей и слушать клавиатуру на предмет комбинации клавиш

И вот вылез баг:
нужно чтоб при нажатии комбинации клавиш остальная система игнорировала её
например: нажал я ctrl+n, программа отработала, но система реагирует на нажатие n, вводя её в, например, строку браузера, или открывая новое окно

e.handled = true - не помогло,  так как блочит любое нажатие ctrl или n

пробую e.handled по условию - вообще магия - ctrl изменяет поведение, а вот n продолжает работать
опыты показали, что, похоже, моя программа далеко не первая в очереди обработчиков нажатия n

Честно говоря, я затрудняюсь объяснить, как именно себя ведёт алгоритм, так как тестировал миллион вариантов расположения e.handled = true и уже запутался, но вот для примера:

e.handled = true, расположенный без условий в самом начале обработчика отлично выключает ctrl и n по всей системе

e.handled = true при условии нажатия именно n и всех предыдущих клавиш попросту не работает, как вот здесь:

```
 private void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //e.Handled = true;
            if (_combinaison.IndexOf(e.KeyCode) == _combinaison.Count - 1)
            {
                bool before_pressed = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < _combinaison.IndexOf(e.KeyCode); i++)
                {
                    if (_pressed[i] == false)
                    {
                        before_pressed = false;
                    }
                }

                if (before_pressed == true)
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                    _f(_combinaison);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _pressed[_combinaison.IndexOf(e.KeyCode)] = true;
            }

        }
```

Вот мой код:

```
class Combinaison
    {
        public delegate void EventFunction(List<Keys> keys);

        private globalKeyboardHook _gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();
        private EventFunction _f;
        private List<Keys> _combinaison;
        private List<bool> _pressed = new List<bool>();


        public Combinaison(List<Keys> combinaison, EventFunction f)
        {
            _f = f;
            _combinaison = combinaison;
            foreach (Keys k in _combinaison)
            {
                _gkh.HookedKeys.Add(k);
                _pressed.Add(false);
            }
            _gkh.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyDown);
            _gkh.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(gkh_KeyUp);
        }

        private void gkh_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {


            if (_combinaison.IndexOf(e.KeyCode) == _combinaison.Count - 1)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }


            _pressed[_combinaison.IndexOf(e.KeyCode)] = false;
        }

        private void gkh_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            if (_combinaison.IndexOf(e.KeyCode) == _combinaison.Count - 1)
            {

                bool before_pressed = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < _combinaison.IndexOf(e.KeyCode); i++)
                {
                    if (_pressed[i] == false)
                    {
                        before_pressed = false;
                    }
                }


                if (before_pressed == true)
                {
                    _f(_combinaison);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                _pressed[_combinaison.IndexOf(e.KeyCode)] = true;
            }

        }
    } 

    class globalKeyboardHook
    {
        #region Constant, Structure and Delegate Definitions
        /// <summary>
        /// defines the callback type for the hook
        /// </summary>
        public delegate int keyboardHookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

        public struct keyboardHookStruct
        {
            public int vkCode;
            public int scanCode;
            public int flags;
            public int time;
            public int dwExtraInfo;
        }

        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
        const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
        const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;
        #endregion

        #region Instance Variables
        /// <summary>
        /// The collections of keys to watch for
        /// </summary>
        public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Handle to the hook, need this to unhook and call the next hook
        /// </summary>
        IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;
        #endregion

        #region Events
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when one of the hooked keys is pressed
        /// </summary>
        public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when one of the hooked keys is released
        /// </summary>
        public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;
        #endregion

        #region Constructors and Destructors
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="globalKeyboardHook"/> class and installs the keyboard hook.
        /// </summary>
        public globalKeyboardHook()
        {
            hook();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Releases unmanaged resources and performs other cleanup operations before the
        /// <see cref="globalKeyboardHook"/> is reclaimed by garbage collection and uninstalls the keyboard hook.
        /// </summary>
        ~globalKeyboardHook()
        {
            unhook();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Installs the global hook
        /// </summary>
        public void hook()
        {
            IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
            hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProc, hInstance, 0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Uninstalls the global hook
        /// </summary>
        public void unhook()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The callback for the keyboard hook
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="code">The hook code, if it isn't >= 0, the function shouldn't do anyting</param>
        /// <param name="wParam">The event type</param>
        /// <param name="lParam">The keyhook event information</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int hookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam)
        {
            if (code >= 0)
            {
                Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
                if (HookedKeys.Contains(key))
                {
                    KeyEventArgs kea = new KeyEventArgs(key);
                    if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null))
                    {
                        KeyDown(this, kea);
                    }
                    else if ((wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) && (KeyUp != null))
                    {
                        KeyUp(this, kea);
                    }
                    if (kea.Handled)
                        return 1;
                }
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wParam, ref lParam);
        }
        #endregion

        #region DLL imports
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the windows hook, do the desired event, one of hInstance or threadId must be non-null
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="idHook">The id of the event you want to hook</param>
        /// <param name="callback">The callback.</param>
        /// <param name="hInstance">The handle you want to attach the event to, can be null</param>
        /// <param name="threadId">The thread you want to attach the event to, can be null</param>
        /// <returns>a handle to the desired hook</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, keyboardHookProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

        /// <summary>
        /// Unhooks the windows hook.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hInstance">The hook handle that was returned from SetWindowsHookEx</param>
        /// <returns>True if successful, false otherwise</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

        /// <summary>
        /// Calls the next hook.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="idHook">The hook id</param>
        /// <param name="nCode">The hook code</param>
        /// <param name="wParam">The wparam.</param>
        /// <param name="lParam">The lparam.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the library.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="lpFileName">Name of the library</param>
        /// <returns>A handle to the library</returns>
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: WPF или Winforns? Реализация сильно отличается. И при чем тут dll?

Comment: И `e.Handled` вам не поможет, совсем, потому что регистрация горячих клавиш делается по-другому. Сейчас вы просто реализовали кейлоггер, он может только слушать.

Comment: Winforms
dll для хуков на клавиатуру, т.к. хоткеи должны работать вне программы

Comment: а что поможет? :)

Comment: Поможет мой ответ, опубликованный ниже.

Comment: Дописал класс для горячих клавиш, ссылка в конце ответа.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужна регистрация глобальных горячих клавиш в системе, тогда они будут перехватываться, а не прослушиваться.

Вот, нашел в старых архивах такой класс.

*Прошу прощения, класс не оптимизирован но это я писал почти 7 лет назад собирая инфу по англоязычному интернету. Потом проект был переписан под WPF, а это просто архивная копия того, что было под Winforms. Сейчас я бы не стал регистрировать каждый раз `MessageFilter` на каждую горячую клавишу, а зарегистрировал бы один, и он бы ловил все (наверное, надо тестировать). Но вы можете проверить и доработать.*

```csharp
public sealed class HotKey : IMessageFilter, IDisposable
{
    public event KeyEventHandler HotKeyPressed;
    public event EventHandler KeyChanged;
    public event EventHandler KeyModifierChanged;

    private readonly int _id;

    #region Native win32 API

    private const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, KeyModifiers fsModifiers, Keys vk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    [Flags]
    public enum KeyModifiers
    {
        None = 0,
        Alt = 1,
        Control = 2,
        Shift = 4,
        Windows = 8
    }

    #endregion

    public IntPtr Handle { get; set; }

    private Keys _key = Keys.None;
    private KeyModifiers _keyModifier;
    public bool isKeyRegistered = false;

    public HotKey(IntPtr handle)
    {
        Handle = handle;
        _id = GetHashCode();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
        if (isKeyRegistered && !UnregisterHotKey(Handle, _id))
            throw new ApplicationException("Failed to unregister hotkey");
        isKeyRegistered = false;
    }

    public void RegisterHotKey()
    {
        if (_key == Keys.None || _keyModifier == KeyModifiers.None)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (isKeyRegistered && !UnregisterHotKey(Handle, _id))
            throw new ApplicationException("Failed to unregister hotkey");
        if (!RegisterHotKey(Handle, _id, _keyModifier, _key))
            throw new ApplicationException("Failed to register hotkey");
        isKeyRegistered = true;
    }

    [Bindable(true), Category("HotKey")]
    public Keys Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
        set
        {
            if (_key != value)
            {
                _key = value;
                OnKeyChanged(new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true), Category("HotKey")]
    public KeyModifiers KeyModifier
    {
        get { return _keyModifier; }

        set
        {
            if (_keyModifier != value)
            {
                _keyModifier = value;
                OnKeyModifierChanged(new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_HOTKEY:
                if ((int)m.WParam == _id)
                {
                    KeyEventArgs args = new KeyEventArgs((IsButtonDown(m.LParam, KeyModifiers.Alt) ? Keys.Alt : Keys.None)
                            | (IsButtonDown(m.LParam, KeyModifiers.Control) ? Keys.Control : Keys.None)
                            | (IsButtonDown(m.LParam, KeyModifiers.Shift) ? Keys.Shift : Keys.None) | Key);

                    OnHotKeyPressed(args);
                    return true;
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static bool IsButtonDown(IntPtr ptr, KeyModifiers keyModifiers)
    {
        return Convert.ToBoolean(((long)ptr) & (long)keyModifiers);
    }

    private void OnHotKeyPressed(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        HotKeyPressed?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private void OnKeyChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterHotKey();
        KeyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private void OnKeyModifierChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterHotKey();
        KeyModifierChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Использование

```csharp
public HotKey RegisterHotKey(Keys key, HotKey.KeyModifiers modifiers)
{         
    HotKey hk = new HotKey(this.Handle);
    hk.KeyModifier = modifiers;
    hk.Key = key;
    hk.HotKeyPressed += new KeyEventHandler(KeyHandler);
    if (!hk.isKeyRegistered)
    {
        hk.Dispose();
        hk = null;
    }
    return hk;
}

public void UnRegisterHotkey(HotKey hotkey)
{
    hotkey?.Dispose();
}

private void KeyHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string hotkey = e.Control ? "Ctrl+" : "";
    hotkey += e.Alt ? "Alt+" : "";
    hotkey += e.Shift ? "Shift+" : "";
    hotkey += e.KeyValue >= 28 && e.KeyValue <= 57 ? e.KeyCode.ToString().Substring(1) : e.KeyCode.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(hotkey); // покажет, что нажалось
}
```

Регистрация

```csharp
HotKey h = RegisterHotKey(Keys.D1, HotKey.KeyModifiers.Control); // Crtl + 1
```

Отмена регистрации

```csharp
UnRegisterHotkey(h);
```

---

### Дополнено

По случаю, дописал класс для работы с горячими клавишами, обновленная версия [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1139921/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-globalhook/1140664#1140664).

Comment: спасибо, сейчас буду тестировать :)

Comment: @AnronGalaburda хорошо, но у меня есть много вопросов к коду, который я опубликовал, просто переписывать его долго, а времени мало, поэтому я решил побыстрее дать ответ, а вы бы смогли его сами привести в порядок, главное - он рабочий, и безотказно служил мне несколько лет.

Comment: Производительность достаточна для моей задачи
так что пока трогать код не буду