# При открытой игре не работает globalHook

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, insert, key

Написал небольшой органайзер для админов одного из проектов GTA 5 RP.
Внутри программы есть функция "Режим последовательной работы".
**Пример работы режима**
[image: Пример]

Так вот.... Если работать сначало с приложением, а затем не закрывая AdminReports запустить GTA 5, то внутри GTA данный режим работать не будет, он попросту не реагирует, такое чувство, что GTA перекрывает это. Решается данная проблема перезапуском ADminReports.
Как то можно обойти перезапуск и сделать все по человечески?
Заранее спасибо.

**Исходники всего проекта** (Visual Studio 2019 C# WinForms): https://github.com/mihail727/AdminReports

**Сам хук** (Version 1): https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C
[image]
[image]

**Реализация внутри проекта:**
**MainForm** (Конструктор):

```
actHook = new UserActivityHook();  
actHook.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(GlobalKeyPress);
```

**Event для глобал хук:**

```cs
private async void GlobalKeyPress(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isCopyPast)
            {
                if (textRow == null)
                {
                    ShowProgress("Ошибка данных");
                    return;
                }

                Clipboard.SetText(textRow[currentColumn]);
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Task.Delay(50);
                    SendKeys.Send("^V");
                });
                ShowProgress("Было скопировано и выведено: " + textRow[currentColumn]);
                currentColumn++;
            }
            else
                ShowProgress("Режим последовательной вставки не включен");
```

textRow - коллекция строк, которые как раз таки последовательно и выводятся по нажатию на Ctrl + V.

## **Спасибо за решение проблемы пользователю с ником *aepot*.**

Изменения после которых все заработало:

1. Конструктор MainForm:

```cs
_hotKey = new HotKey(Handle, Keys.V, HotKeyModifiers.Control);
_hotKey.HotKeyPressed += OnHotKeyPressed;
```

2. Был переписан метод GlobalKeyPress ----> OnHotKeyPressed:

```cs
private async void OnHotKeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isCopyPast)
            {
                if(textRow == null)
                {
                    ShowProgress("Данные из строки не сохранены");
                    return;
                }

                Clipboard.SetText(textRow[CurrentColumn]);
                await Task.Delay(50);
                _hotKey.Enabled = false;

                PressCtrlV();
                _hotKey.Enabled = true;

                ShowProgress("Было скопировано и выведено: " + textRow[CurrentColumn]);

                CurrentColumn++;
            }
            else
                ShowProgress("Режим последовательной вставки не включен");
        }
```

3. Естественно был убран предыдущий хук и добавлен новый предложенный пользователем aepot.

Comment: А что делает хук? Кейлоггер? Какую задачу он решает? Или только Crtl+V? Вы пробовали запустить программу от имени администратора? Вы пробовали использовать перехват горячих клавиш `RegisterHotKey`? Если да, то что именно вас не устраивает? Перестает срабатывать горячая клавиша (проверяли ли точкой останова)? Или игра не видит изменений в буфере обмена?

Comment: На вашем месте я бы для специальной своей кастомной вставки [зарегистрировал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1125626/%d0%93%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b8/1125784#1125784) бы альтернативную горячую клавишу, например `Ctrl+1`. А затем бы менял буфер обмена и эмулировал бы нажатие `Ctrl+V` через Win32 API `keybd_event` или `SendInput`. В этом случае хотя-бы не пришлось бы париться с включением/отключением режима специальной вставки, потому что обычный `Ctrl+V` продолжит работать.

Comment: Зарегистрированная горячая комбинация перехватывается полностью, она не является прозрачной в отличие от хука. Но есть большой плюс, вашу программу не будут ругать антивирусы и не будут требоваться права администратора, потому что в данном случае программа не будет себя вести как кейлоггер.

Comment: Только есть нюанс, менять буфер надо в UI потоке, а эмулировать `Ctrl+V` надо асинхронно, освободив UI поток. `Clipboard.SetText(...); Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(50); SendCtrlV(); });`

Comment: @aepot В общем попытался сделать через `SendKeys.Send("^V")`.... Есть проблема теперь вставка срабатывает даже когда нажата только клавиша Ctrl

Comment: Добавьте новый код в вопрос.

Comment: @aepot Готово, обновил блок кода

Comment: `if (isCopyPast)` а где проверка на то, что именно сейчас нажато пользователем?

Comment: @aepot а то есть вы предлагаете проверять на нажатие комбинации а затем эмулировать?

Comment: У GTA V есть несколько возможных режимов получения данных от мыши: от raw до DirectInput, поэкспериментируйте

Comment: @Kir_Antipov увы, тест под разными режимами не дало никаких сдвигов

Comment: @Supp, в таком случае воспользуйтесь [Raw Input](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input), так как события, полученные от устройства напрямую, нельзя перекрыть. [Пример реализации для мыши](https://github.com/Kir-Antipov/GlobalHook/blob/master/GlobalHook.Core.Windows/Mouse/RawMouseHook.cs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все-таки лучше такое делать через регистрацию горячих клавиш. Написал пример, который делает то что вам нужно с асинхронным обработчиком нажатия горячей комбинации.

**Возможности решения**

- юзер может задать любую комбинацию горячих клавиш в текстбоксе `textBoxHotkey` (в дизайнере установлен как `ReadOnly`).
- ввести любой текст во второй большой текстбокс `textBox1`
- включить или отключит хоткей в `checkBox1`
- если хоткей активен, `textBoxHotkey` окрасится в зеленый, если ошибка регистрации клавиши - в красный, если неактивен - серый, если сейчас редактируется - белый.
- если хоткей активен, то при нажатии на хоткей, произойдет вставка из буфера обмена текста, который расположен в `textBox1`

Потребуется энумератор клавиатурных модификаторов

**HotKeyModifiers.cs**

```csharp
[Flags]
public enum HotKeyModifiers : int
{
    None = 0,
    Alt = 1,
    Control = 2,
    Shift = 4,
    Windows = 8
}
```

Далее Win32 API.

**NativeMethods.cs**

```csharp
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void keybd_event(Keys bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern uint MapVirtualKey(Keys uCode, uint uMapType);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, HotKeyModifiers fsModifiers, Keys vk);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
}
```

Сам класс для работы с горячими клавишами

**HotKey.cs**

```csharp
public class HotKey : IMessageFilter, IDisposable
{
    private const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;

    public event KeyEventHandler HotKeyPressed;

    private readonly int _id;
    private bool _enabled;
    public IntPtr Handle { get; }
    public bool Registered { get; private set; }
    public bool Enabled
    {
        get => _enabled;
        set
        {
            if (_enabled != value)
            {
                _enabled = value;
                if (_enabled)
                    Register();
                else
                    Unregister();
            }
        }
    }

    public Keys Key { get; private set; }
    public HotKeyModifiers Modifiers { get; private set; }

    public HotKey(IntPtr handle, Keys key, HotKeyModifiers modifiers)
    {
        Handle = handle;
        _id = GetHashCode();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        ChangeKeys(key, modifiers);
    }

    private void Register()
    {
        if (!Registered && Key != Keys.None && Modifiers != HotKeyModifiers.None)
            Registered = NativeMethods.RegisterHotKey(Handle, _id, Modifiers, Key);
    }

    private void Unregister()
    {
        if (Registered)
        {
            NativeMethods.UnregisterHotKey(Handle, _id);
            Registered = false;
        }
    }

    public void ChangeKeys(Keys key, HotKeyModifiers modifiers)
    {
        if (Enabled) Unregister();
        Key = key;
        Modifiers = modifiers;
        if (Enabled) Register();
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY && (int)m.WParam == _id)
        {
            KeyEventArgs args = new KeyEventArgs((IsButtonDown(m.LParam, HotKeyModifiers.Alt) ? Keys.Alt : Keys.None)
                            | (IsButtonDown(m.LParam, HotKeyModifiers.Control) ? Keys.Control : Keys.None)
                            | (IsButtonDown(m.LParam, HotKeyModifiers.Shift) ? Keys.Shift : Keys.None) | Key);
            OnHotKeyPressed(args);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private bool IsButtonDown(IntPtr ptr, HotKeyModifiers modifiers) => Convert.ToBoolean(((long)ptr) & (long)modifiers);
    private void OnHotKeyPressed(KeyEventArgs e) => HotKeyPressed?.Invoke(this, e);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private bool _disposed;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {

            }
            Unregister();
            Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    ~HotKey()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

- `Enabled` - включен/выключен
- `Registerd` - зарегистрирован/не зарегистрирован

Класс для преобразования комбинации клавиш в строку и обратно

**HotKeyConverter.cs**

```csharp
public static class HotKeyConverter
{
    public static string Keys2String(Keys key, HotKeyModifiers modifiers)
    {
        string hotkey =
            (modifiers.HasFlag(HotKeyModifiers.Control) ? "Ctrl+" : string.Empty) +
            (modifiers.HasFlag(HotKeyModifiers.Alt) ? "Alt+" : string.Empty) +
            (modifiers.HasFlag(HotKeyModifiers.Shift) ? "Shift+" : string.Empty);
        if (hotkey.Length != 0 && (key < Keys.LShiftKey || key > Keys.RMenu) && key != Keys.LWin && key != Keys.RWin && key != Keys.ShiftKey && key != Keys.ControlKey && key != Keys.Menu) //exclude modifiers as keys
        {
            string keyCode = key.ToString();
            if (key >= Keys.D0 && key <= Keys.D9) keyCode = keyCode.Substring(1);
            else if (key == Keys.Oem3) keyCode = "~";
            hotkey += keyCode;
        }
        if (hotkey.Length == 0) hotkey = "None";
        return hotkey;
    }
    public static HotKeyModifiers GetModifier(string hotkey)
    {
        HotKeyModifiers result = HotKeyModifiers.None;
        if (hotkey?.Length > 1 && hotkey.Contains("+"))
        {
            string modifiers = hotkey.Remove(hotkey.LastIndexOf('+')).Replace("Ctrl", "Control");
            foreach (HotKeyModifiers m in Enum.GetValues(typeof(HotKeyModifiers)))
            {
                if (modifiers.Contains(m.ToString())) result |= m;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static Keys GetKey(string hotkey)
    {
        if (hotkey?.Length > 1 && hotkey.Contains("+") && !hotkey.EndsWith("+"))
        {
            string key = hotkey.Split('+').Last().Replace("~", "Oem3");
            if (key.Length == 1 && key[0] >= '0' && key[0] <= '9') key = 'D' + key;
            return Enum.TryParse(key, out Keys result) ? result : Keys.None;
        }
        return Keys.None;
    }
}
```

Ну и сама форма

**Form1.cs**

```csharp
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private HotKey _hotKey;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBoxHotkey_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Keys key = e.KeyCode;
        HotKeyModifiers modifiers = e.Control ? HotKeyModifiers.Control : HotKeyModifiers.None;
        modifiers |= e.Alt ? HotKeyModifiers.Alt : HotKeyModifiers.None;
        modifiers |= e.Shift ? HotKeyModifiers.Shift : HotKeyModifiers.None;
        if (sender is TextBox textBox && !(modifiers == HotKeyModifiers.None && (key == Keys.Enter || key == Keys.Escape)))
        {
            textBox.Text = HotKeyConverter.Keys2String(key, modifiers);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void textBoxHotkey_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        HotKeyModifiers modifiers = e.Control ? HotKeyModifiers.Control : HotKeyModifiers.None;
        modifiers |= e.Alt ? HotKeyModifiers.Alt : HotKeyModifiers.None;
        modifiers |= e.Shift ? HotKeyModifiers.Shift : HotKeyModifiers.None;
        if (sender is TextBox textBox && (textBox.Text.Length > 1 && textBox.Text.EndsWith("+") || textBox.Text.Length == 1))
        {
            textBox.Text = modifiers == HotKeyModifiers.None ? "None" : HotKeyConverter.Keys2String(e.KeyCode, modifiers);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    private void textBoxHotkey_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _hotKey.Enabled = false;
        textBoxHotkey.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
    }

    private void textBoxHotkey_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxHotkey.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
        if (sender is TextBox textBox && textBox.Text != "None")
        {
            _hotKey.ChangeKeys(HotKeyConverter.GetKey(textBox.Text), HotKeyConverter.GetModifier(textBox.Text));
            _hotKey.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked;
            SetTextBoxColor();
        }
    }

    private void SetTextBoxColor()
    {
        if (_hotKey.Enabled && textBoxHotkey.Text != "None")
        {
            textBoxHotkey.BackColor = _hotKey.Registered ? Color.LightGreen : Color.LightPink;
        }
        else
            textBoxHotkey.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _hotKey = new HotKey(Handle, Keys.None, HotKeyModifiers.None);
        _hotKey.HotKeyPressed += OnHotKeyPressed;
    }

    private async void OnHotKeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
            do
            {
                await Task.Delay(50);
            }
            while (ModifierKeys != Keys.None);
            PressCtrlV();
        }
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is CheckBox checkBox)
        {
            _hotKey.Enabled = checkBox.Checked;
            SetTextBoxColor();
        }
    }

    private void PressCtrlV()
    {
        NativeMethods.keybd_event(Keys.ControlKey, (byte)NativeMethods.MapVirtualKey(Keys.ControlKey, 0), 0, 0);
        NativeMethods.keybd_event(Keys.V, (byte)NativeMethods.MapVirtualKey(Keys.V, 0), 0, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        NativeMethods.keybd_event(Keys.V, (byte)NativeMethods.MapVirtualKey(Keys.V, 0), 0x02, 0);
        NativeMethods.keybd_event(Keys.ControlKey, (byte)NativeMethods.MapVirtualKey(Keys.ControlKey, 0), 0x02, 0);
    }
}
```

Пробуйте, тестируйте. Кстати, это не будет работать, если вы выбрали в качестве горячих клавиш `Ctrl+V`, чтобы заработало, нужно снимать `HotKey` с регистрации.

Например, можно обработчик доработать вот так

```csharp
private async void OnHotKeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
        do
        {
            await Task.Delay(50);
        }
        while (ModifierKeys != Keys.None);
        _hotKey.Enabled = false;
        PressCtrlV();
        _hotKey.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```