# Куда вставить код c# на winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет, я очень новичок в программировании.
Куда бы я не вставлял код, он всегда выдает ошибку. 2 месяца я не могу продвинуться, я читал учебник c++ и форум windows microsoft, но не нашел ответ. Моя задача сделать так, чтобы при нажатии быстрой клавиши ctrl+shift+P (или ctrl+up+P) в окне другой программы выполнялись действия: ctrl+V, ожидание 4 секунды, enter, 7 раз Tab, ожидание, enter, ожидание, скролл вниз, ожидание, Ins, ctrl+enter, ожидание 4 секунды, 9 раз Tab. И чтобы в будущем я мог менять сами действия местами, программировать.
Пробелы в коде расставлены правильно в visual studio 2019. Помогите, друзья, куда вставлять сам код.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class CIA_Special_Agents : Form
       {
       public CIA_Special_Agents()
       {
        InitializeComponent();
       }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void CIA_Special_Agents_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }

        else
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void label9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=windowsdesktop-5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вопрос звучит как "напишите мне автокликер с нуля". Разделите задачу на мелкие подзадачи и решайте по отдельности. Начните писать код. Почитайте или посмотрите курсы по шарпу. Незнание основ языка и ООП не позволит вам продвинуться в задаче и сфокусироваться на проблеме. Двигание кнопочек в дизайнере формы и кликание по ним знаний не добавит.

Видите метод `CIA_Special_Agents_Load`? Этот метод называется "обработчик события `Form.Load`". Код в этом методе выполняется 1 раз при загрузке формы, можете начать писать стартовый код в этом методе между фигурными скобками. Собственно это и есть ответ на ваш вопрос.

У формы много разных событий, их список можно посмотреть в дизайнере формы, выделив форму и нажав на кнопочку с молниец в правом нижнем углу. Все эти события возникают в разных условиях, например `Form.Closing` вызывается перед закрытием формы, дважды кликнув по событию можно создать для него новый обработчик, или подключить уже написанный выбрав из списка, предлагаемого студией. События есть не только у формы, но и у всех без исключения элементов на ней.

Подскажу еще только, чтобы запустить действие при нажатии комбинации горячих клавиш, вам нужно [это решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1140664/373567).

А для симуляции ввода может помочь старый добрый NuGet пакет **InputSimulator**, ну если конечно вы не желаете напрямую работать с методом Win32 API `SendInput`, сразу скажу, задача непростая, с пакетом получится легче.

Чтобы редактировать список действий, создайте класс, содержащий данные о действии и коллекцию из этих классов. Подключите коллекцию например к `DataGridView`. Как это сделать - показано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1199692/373567).

Как видите, много работы. Но если тупо копировать чужой код к себе в проект, ничего хорошего не выйдет, надо знать основы. Начать изучать их можно например по этим [коротким и веселым видео](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ). Я сам по ним когда-то начинал учиться.

Comment: Зачем так сложно? Вроде бы всё вызовом [одного метода](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) делается?

Comment: Хотя нет, он же ещё скролл хочет...