# Не работает приложение при свернутом состоянии c# windows

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть действие по нажатию привязанной клавиши, это MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, когда я сворачиваю приложение и нажимаю на привязанную клавишу, у меня никакого действия не происходит, однако когда я захожу в само приложение у меня всё работает
Код :

```
        public void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keys.A <= e.KeyCode && e.KeyCode <= Keys.Z)
        {//Character keys
            textBox1.Text = e.KeyCode.ToString();
        }
        if (Keys.F1 <= e.KeyCode && e.KeyCode <= Keys.F9)
        { //func keys (F)
            textBox1.Text = e.KeyCode.ToString();
        }
        if (Keys.D0 <= e.KeyCode && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9)
        { //number keys
            textBox1.Text = e.KeyCode.ToString().Replace("D", null);
        }

        if (textBox1.TextLength == 1)
        {
            button2.Enabled = true;
        }
   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(UInt32 dwFlags, UInt32 dx, UInt32 dy, UInt32 cButtons, IntPtr dwExtraInfo);
    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
        public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
        public const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
        public const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;
 private void button3_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        KeysConverter kc = new KeysConverter();
        string keystring = textBox1.Text;
        Keys keyspecial = (Keys)kc.ConvertFromString(keystring);
        if (e.KeyCode == keyspecial)
        {

            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 1, 1, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 1, 1, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: Осталось угадать ваш код и придумать решение. :) Но телепатически могу предположить, что вам следует копать в сторону "как сделать Mouse Hook".

Comment: Всё, код добавил.

Comment: Ну, код в обработчике события, как вы возмете кнопку button3 в клавиатурный фокус в свернутом окне? Никак, это невозможно. Предполагаю, что вы хотите, чтобы код выполнился при нажатии на клавишу или комбинацию клавиш, из кода непонятно что именно. Но я попробую предположить, что это комбинация горячих клавиш - [оно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1140664/373567)?

Comment: Это при нажатии на выбранную пользователем клавишу (не комбинацию)

Comment: Я пробовал заменить button3_KeyUp на Form1_KeyUp,тож не помогло

Comment: И не должно помочь, вы же внимательно прочитали комментарий про клавиатурный фокус выше? Тогда у меня нет готовых ответов, но решение - скорее всего Keyboard Hook. То есть кейлоггер, на такое решение кстати может ругаться антивирус. Еще разница в том, что если вы используете хук, то клавиша просто отслеживается, то есть ее нажатие одновременно отработает как для обычной клавиши, например буква напечатается, так и запустит код внутри вашего приложения. В случае с горячими клавишами, регистрация монопольная. То есть ваше приложение полностью перехватит на себя все нажатия комбинации.

Comment: Вы же правильно поняли суть проблемы? У вас вообще не вызывается обработчик `button3_KeyUp`. Код внутри него не при чем.

Comment: Хорошо, я всё понял