# Как скопировать текст в буфер обмена другими горячими клавишами?

Tags: c#

Сабж.
К примеру у меня есть выделенный текст. Я хочу нажать shift+d и тем самым как бы повторить действие ctrl+c. Можно конечно эмулировать нажатие ctrl+c при нажатии shift+d но мне кажется это костыльным решением.

Comment: Текст выделенный где? В вашем приложении или чужом?

Comment: Чужом.  
8 символов

Comment: Смотреть в сторону хуков (hooks). Ещё уточняющий вопрос: приложение для Винды или кроссплатформенное (Линукс, Макось)?

Comment: А если вам потребуется большую букву D напечатать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1140664/373567, только через эмуляцию Crtl+C можно сделать. Пользуюсь этим способом в промышленных масштабах, не кашляю.