# C#: Bind горячих клавиш на вызов функции в консольном приложении

Tags: c#

В `Visual Studio` создал новый проект типа `Консольное приложение`. Мне нужна какая-то реализация возможности назначать одну горячую клавишу или сочетание нескольких на вызов какого-либо метода.

Нужна возможность назначить, например, сочетание `ctrl+shift+alt+esc` на вызов метода. При этом чтобы была **возможность блокировать** это же сочетание во всех других местах. Например, при назначении сочетанию `ctrl+shift+esc` *(вызов диспетчера задач)* вызова какого-либо метода, должен выполняться только метод, а диспетчер задач не должен вызываться.

---

Практически везде все указывают на метод `Console.ReadKey()`, но это мне не подходит, так как мне нужно, чтобы клавиши считывались даже когда окно консоли **не в фокусе**. То есть [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898182/how-to-handle-key-press-event-in-console-application) и подобные решения не подходят.

Я пробовал подключать к проекту `Библиотеку классов Windows Forms`, чтобы написать такой обработчик самостоятельно, но там, вроде как, для создания обработчика событий нажатия на клавиши нужно добавить этот обработчик к какому-либо объекту, а у меня есть только консоль.

Вроде бы существуют различные библиотеки с реализацией моей "хотелки", но почему-то почти нигде не оставляют примеров использования, а если они и есть, то позволяют назначить сочетание всего 1-2 клавиш.

---

Может быть кто-то может подсказать нужную мне **библиотеку** или **самостоятельную реализацию**?

---

**Мне нужно подобие библиотеки `keyboard` на `Python`:**

```py
import keyboard

# функция для вызова при нажатии горячих клавиш
def function():
    print('Вызван диспетчер задач')

       # назначение / любое сочетание / указание метода / подавление в других приложениях
keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+shift+esc', callback=function, suppress=True)
keyboard.wait()
```

Comment: Самостоятельная реализация: https://github.com/Zergatul/Zergatul.Obs.InputOverlay/blob/master/src/WindowsHook.cs Пример использования в `InputHook.cs` (импорты и константы в `WinApi.cs`) В функции `KeyboardHookCallback` стоит `return CallNextHookEx` что значит передать событие следующему обработчику. Если возвратить 0, то будет эффект подавления. Подавить комбинации типа `Alt+Tab` не получится, на счет диспетчера не уверен.

Comment: Сори, ошибся с возвращаемым значением, должно быть не 0: If the hook procedure processed the message, it may return a nonzero value to prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window procedure.

Comment: @Zergatul, как я понял это плагин для OBS. Я только начал учить шарп, поэтому прошу подсказку) Мне по сути нужен только файл `WindowsHook.cs`?

Comment: И `WinApi.cs` нужен.

Comment: `При этом чтобы была возможность блокировать это же сочетание во всех других местах.` Перехват горячих клавиш не хуком делается, а двумя методами Win API `RegisterHotkey` и `UnregisterHotkey`. А чтобы принимать сообщения от системы о том, что они были нажаты - нужен Message Loop, то есть нативное окно Windows.

Comment: @aepot ну так если нет окна, то хуки единственный выход?)

Comment: @aepot а как это без окна в `Python` `keyboard` работает?

Comment: Ну окно можно и не отображать. Вот кстати пример с использованием окна winforms https://stackoverflow.com/a/3654821/12888024 Хуки можно, но они не блокируют горячие клавиши. То есть вы можете узнать, что нажато но на реакцию других приложений повлиять не можете. Кстати перехватить комбинацию Ctrl+Shift+Esc не получится, потому что она уже зарегистрирована в системе (хотя можете попытаться) диспетчером задач а вот Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Esc у меня получилось без проблем.

Comment: @aepot да, это я тоже видел и пробовал - там, к сожалению, можно назначить всего 2 кнопки. Я пробовал передавать массив или использовать `|` между передаваемыми значениями, но так и не получилось сделать

Comment: Ничего подобного, назначить можно любую комбинацию. Вот [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1125784/373567) для винформ. Можете попробовать скомбинировать мой класс и невидимое окно. Должно получиться. Для моего примера будет так `RegisterHotKey(Keys.Escape, HotKey.KeyModifiers.Control | HotKey.KeyModifiers.Shift | HotKey.KeyModifiers.Alt);`

Comment: Понял, спасибо за помощь!