# Скрывать и отображать форму, созданную в Windows forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть готовая программа, которая содержит одну форму. Форма отображается поверх всех окон widows, но иногда ее необходимо скрывать, работать с другими программами, затем снова восстанавливать. Я хочу реализовать скрытие с помощью нажатия клавиш. Что-то вроде этого:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Q)
   this.Hide();
```

Далее при повторном нажатии на эту клавишу окно должно появляться. Проблема в том, что при вызове метода this.Show() форма не появляется. Та же ситуация с this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal - форма не разворачивается из панели задач после присваивания FormWindowState.Minimized.
Единственное, что удалось придумать - уменьшать и увеличивать размер формы при нажатии на клавишу. Окей, это сработало, но тут возникла еще одна проблема: при нажатии на "нерабочую" область форма перестает реагировать на нажатие клавиши. Это певедение естейственно и я догадываюсь почему это происходит, но задача остается нерешенной.

Вопрос 1: как возвращать форму из скрытого состояния, используя Hide()/ FormWindowState.Minimized?

Вопрос 2: есть ли более легкий способ реализации скрытия и отображения формы с учетом взаимодейсвия с нерабочей областью?

Comment: На клавиши форма реагирует только тогда, когда она в фокусе, то есть окно активно. То что вы хотите, можно сделать через Keyboard Hook, но я не советую реагировать глобально в системе на просто клавиши. Вдруг я это Q нажму просто печатая текст в другом приложении, верно? Поэтому советую использовать комбинации клавиш (горячие клавиши/hotkeys), например `Ctrl+Q`, решение [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1125784/373567).

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Безусловно то, что я искал!

Comment: Если вопрос более не актуален, можете удалить его. Не вижу способа дать на него подходящий под формат StackOverflow ответ.